# JMockit unable to mock more than one instance of class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I want to create a Map that holds Strings as its keys and mocked instances of class `Candidate` as its values.

```
    Map<String, Long> domainNameToId = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    domainNameToId.put("farmaciapuentezurita.es", 1234l);
    domainNameToId.put("vivefarma.com", 2345l);
    domainNameToId.put("eurofarmacia.com", 3456l);

    Map<String, Candidate> expectedCandidates = new HashMap<String, Candidate>();
    for(String domain : domainNameToId.keySet()) {
        final Candidate cand = new MockUp<Candidate>() {
            @Mock Long getDomainId() { return domainNameToId.get(domain); } // private method
            @Mock boolean validateAndPrepare() { return true; }
            @Mock String getRepresentingName() { return domain; }
        }.getMockInstance();
        expectedCandidates.put(domain, cand);
    }
```

**The above code used to work before upgrading JMockit from 1.20 to 1.28**.

Now I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid attempt to get uninitialized instance of class com.urlservice.data.Candidate from stateless mockup
>       at ...

I read the documentation and tried to use `new MockUp(T targetInstance)` instead in the following fashion (this is the loop's body):

```
final Candidate cand = new Candidate(domain);
new MockUp<Candidate>(cand) {
    @Mock Long getDomainId() { return domainNameToId.get(domain); }  // private method
    @Mock boolean validateAndPrepare() { return true; }
    @Mock String getRepresentingName() { return domain; }
};
```

The result was very strange - the first Candidate was mocked properly while the rest of the mocked candidates weren't mocked at all and their real methods were called.

I tried to revert back to the `Expectations` API:

```
final Candidate cand = new Candidate(domain);
new Expectations(cand) {{
    cand.getDomainId(); result = domainNameToId.get(domain);  // Had to make it public :-(
    cand.validateAndPrepare(); result = true;
    cand.getRepresentingName(); result = domain;
}};
```

to no avail:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Already mocked: class com.urlservice.data.Candidate
>       at...

I really want to upgrade to the latest version but I can't find a workaround to this problem.

**UPDATE:** I didn't manage to reproduce this issue in any version up to 1.28, so I guess this is the version in which it was introduced.

In addition, related to my 2nd example (`new MockUp(T targetInstance)`), I looked at the source code of class `MockUp` line 402 and it looks to me like the expected behavior is to NOT mock any specific target instance other than the first one:

```
  MockUp<?> previousMockUp = findPreviouslyFakedClassIfMockUpAlreadyApplied();

  if (previousMockUp != null) {
     targetType = previousMockUp.targetType;
     mockedClass = previousMockUp.mockedClass;
     return;  // Input param targetInstance is disregarded
  }
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE2:** I came up with a failing test example. It's a bit cumbersome but I'm sure it will get the point through.

```
public class SampleTest {

class TestedClass {
    private IncrementingDependency dep;
    TestedClass(IncrementingDependency dep) { this.dep = dep; }
    public int getVal() { return dep.inc(); }
}

class IncrementingDependency {
    int val;
    public IncrementingDependency(int val) { this.val = val; }
    public int inc() { return ++val; }
}

@Test
public void sampleTest() {
    List<Integer> inputVals = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<TestedClass> incrementingClasses = new ArrayList<TestedClass>();

    for (Integer num : inputVals) {
        IncrementingDependency dep = new IncrementingDependency(num);
        new MockUp<IncrementingDependency>(dep) {
            @Mock int inc() { return num; }  // Mock with different behavior - DON'T INCREMENT
        };
        incrementingClasses.add(new TestedClass(dep));
    }

    assertThat(incrementingClasses.get(0).getVal()).isEqualTo(1); // Passes - 1 wasn't incremented (mocked behavior)
    assertThat(incrementingClasses.get(1).getVal()).isEqualTo(2); // Fails - real code was called and 2 was incremented to 3
    assertThat(incrementingClasses.get(2).getVal()).isEqualTo(3); // We never get to this point
}
}
```

Please note that even if this example wouldn't have failed, the fact that I need to instantiate my dependency before passing it to `MockUp`'s constructor is problematic at best. Isn't the whole point of creating a mock is that you don't need to instantiate it?

Comment: I could not reproduce the "strange" result when using `new MockUp<Candidate>(cand)`. It seems to work fine with 1.28. Could you show a failing example test?

Comment: Note the [API documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/MockUp.html#MockUp-T-) for `Mock<T>(T)` says "only affecting the given instance". So, methods called on any *other* instances of `Candidate` will not go to the `@Mock` method.

Comment: @Rogério Of course, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. I'll try to supply a failing example test ASAP, but doesn't the JMockit code sample I put in the end strongly back up my claim?

Comment: The failing example test also fails with JMockit 1.20; nothing changed in this part from 1.20 to 1.28. Also, I don't get the point of the test: why mock the `IncrementingDependency` at all? Why "mock with diferent behavior"?

Comment: Note the whole point of mocks (and fakes) *in general* is that they "mimic" or "imitate" the *actual (expected) behavior* of the mocked/faked dependency, but without executing the actual implementation. You don't use mocks for *different* behavior.

Comment: @Rogério The purpose of the "test" I supplied was demonstrating functionality that isn't working. Yes, it's not a "valid" test in "real life" terms, but it gets the point through and was good enough to show the malfunction. Yes, this specific issue is not regression (still a bug, though) and is merely a workaround that I tried to apply in order to solve my original problem (first code snippet), which is indeed a regression. You asked for a failing test example of the "strange" result (second snippet) and I supplied one.

Comment: I will re-examine that "previousMockUp" stuff in JMockit's internals, as it looks like it should be improved. This question got too much into it at this point, but it still fails to provide the essential, which is what is the original problem, ie, what's to be tested. It suffers from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closely examining JMockit's actual project unit tests (which are very clear and organized), I managed to solved the issue in a somewhat peculiar manner:

```
private void expectCandidatesFromMap(final Map<String, Long> domainNameToId) {
    Map<String, Candidate> expectedCandidates = new HashMap<String, Candidate>();

    class MockedCandidate extends MockUp<Candidate> {
        private final String domainName;
        private final Long domainId;

        MockedCandidate(String domainName) {
            this.domainName = domainName;
            this.domainId = domainNameToId.get(domainName);
        }

        @Mock Long getDomainId() { return domainId; }
        @Mock String getRepresentingName() { return domainName; }
        @Mock boolean validateAndPrepare() { return true; }
    }

    for (String domain : domainNameToId.keySet()) {
        expectedCandidates.put(domain, new MockedCandidate(domain).getMockInstance());
    }
}
```

Even though my tests now pass, I don't completely understand why the only way to mock a specific instance of a class is by creating another ad-hoc class (as opposed to inlining it anonymously as I was used to prior to this version).

This approach takes a few more lines (private field declaration, ctor implementation), but is arguably more elegant.

It would still be very appreciated if one of JMockit's contributors could shed some light on this matter.

Comment: Actually, this is not the only way (see the `Invocation` class). And it's not necessary to create a named mockup like the above; it just needs to be a "stateful" mockup (with instance fields), which can still be written with an anonymous subclass. The real issue is applying the same mockup class multiple times with different associated mocked instances. This is not supported, as it would require JMockit to maintain an internal map from mocked instances to mockup instances. Which is technically doable, but doesn't fit with the intended usage of the API.

Comment: So basically what I've done here is bypass the intended usage of the API with a named mockup? Can you please elaborate why it's not an intended usage?

Comment: Mock-ups are meant to provide *fake* implementations (of classes, mostly), not to be a convenient way of creating "data" objects with little or no complex/expensive behavior. The test should instead just instantiate the class with the desired state in as many instances it needs. No mocking or faking of said instances, normally.

Comment: So what is the intended convenient way of creating "data" objects with little or no complex/expensive behavior? What if instantiating the class with the desired state is complex and/or expensive and/or practically impossible within the constraints of a big codebase which has been written by many people, some of which don't share the same philosophy as this?

Comment: Nothing in your question says that creating `Candidate` objects is prohibitive. In fact, it even shows a line with `new Candidate(domain)`. I am not going to speculate about imaginary situations for which no code is shown.